# Add dropdown arrow to react-native-modal-selector

Tags: react-native

I'm using the module [react-native-modal-selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irib6.png) to substitute for dropdown menus in my mobile app. I would like the selector input box to have a dropdown arrow as it does on my web version. Any suggestions on how to implement this?

```
<ModalSelector 
   data={playTypeData}
   initValue='Play Type'
   onChange={(option)=>setEventTitle(option.label)}>
   <TextInput 
      style={styles.input}
      editable={false}
      value={eventTitle}
      placeholder={'Play Type'}
   />
</ModalSelector>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   input: {
        height: 60, 
        width: 180, 
        borderColor: 'lightgrey', 
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '300',
        marginBottom: 20,
        paddingLeft:10
    },
});
```

What it looks like:

[[image: What it looks like1]

What i need:

[image: What i want]

Answer (score 0):

```
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

<ModalSelector
   data={playTypeData}
   initValue='Play Type'
   onChange={(option)=>setEventTitle(option.label)}>
   <TextInput 
      style={styles.input}
      editable={false}
      value={eventTitle}
      placeholder={'Play Type'}
   />
</ModalSelector>
<MaterialIcons name='expand-more' size={24} color='#ccc' style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 5, zIndex: -1, }} />
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.